# Moverio bt-350 bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, epson

**Dear community,**

Developing on Moverio BT-350 I came across an issue when trying to play media audio from a bluetooth speaker (having a headset connected in the aux cable).

My objective is to switch audio output from the headset to the bluetooth speaker and viceversa.
This is usually a fairly simple task that android tools already enable us to achieve. We sucessfully achieved this objective in the Moverio bt 200 device but cannot seem to make it in the new bt moverio 350.

I’ll show you the code I wrote before:

First I connected the bluetooth speaker ( no media profile/only phone) and a pair of headphones thru jack.

Bluetooth speaker connected (no media)
[image]

Only phone profile
[image]

My app has two buttons called “switch to bluetooth” and “switch to headphones”.

---

***In the onCreate method we have the play of the media that initially can be heard from the headphones.***

```
Resources res = getResources();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.media2);
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();;
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
mp.setLooping(false);
try {
    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    mp.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mp.start();
```

---

***When clicking the “switch to bluetooth” we have this code***

```
AudioManager mAudioManager;
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
```

---

***When clicking the “switch to headphones” we have this:***

```
AudioManager mAudioManager;
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
```

*The switch in the bt 350 doesent seem to work! ( it does int bt 200)
I attach the systme log because it may be usuefull to help me solve the issue.*

---

***System Log during boot filtering bluetooth errors:***

```
E/BlueZ: APTX: failed to open library libbt-aptx.so (dlopen failed: library "libbt-aptx.so" not found)
E/BluetoothA2dpSink: Could not bind to Bluetooth A2DP Service with Intent { act=android.bluetooth.IBluetoothA2dpSink }
E/BluetoothAvrcpController: Could not bind to Bluetooth AVRCP Controller Service with Intent { act=android.bluetooth.IBluetoothAvrcpController }
E/BluetoothHeadsetClient: Could not bind to Bluetooth Headset Client Service with Intent { act=android.bluetooth.IBluetoothHeadsetClient }
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(ipc_init) path : , size = 18
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(ipc_connect) connect result : 0, errno : 0
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(cmd_connect_cb) cond is  G_IO_NVAL : off
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(cmd_connect_cb) cond is  G_IO_ERR  : off
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(cmd_connect_cb) cond is  G_IO_HUP  : off
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(ipc_connect) connect result : 0, errno : 0
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/main.c):(service_register) service_id is 0x1. (HAL_SERVICE_ID_BLUETOOTH)
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/main.c):(service_register) service_id is 0x2. (HAL_SERVICE_ID_SOCKET)
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/main.c):(service_register) service_id is 0xb. (HAL_SERVICE_ID_MAP_CLIENT)
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/main.c):(service_register) service_id is 0x5. (HAL_SERVICE_ID_HANDSFREE)
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(ipc_init) path : , size = 18
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(ipc_connect) connect result : -1, errno : 111
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(cmd_connect_cb) cond is  G_IO_NVAL : off
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(cmd_connect_cb) cond is  G_IO_ERR  : off
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(cmd_connect_cb) cond is  G_IO_HUP  : on
E/bluetoothd: IPC: command socket connect failed
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/main.c):(service_register) service_id is 0x8. (HAL_SERVICE_ID_AVRCP)
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/main.c):(service_register) service_id is 0x6. (HAL_SERVICE_ID_A2DP)
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(ipc_init) path : , size = 20
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(ipc_connect) connect result : 0, errno : 0
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(cmd_connect_cb) cond is  G_IO_NVAL : off
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(cmd_connect_cb) cond is  G_IO_ERR  : off
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/ipc.c):(cmd_connect_cb) cond is  G_IO_HUP  : off
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/main.c):(service_register) service_id is 0x3. (HAL_SERVICE_ID_HIDHOST)
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/main.c):(service_register) service_id is 0x7. (HAL_SERVICE_ID_HEALTH)
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/main.c):(service_register) service_id is 0x4. (HAL_SERVICE_ID_PAN)
E/bluetoothd: (device/intel/cherrytrail/cht_cr_rvp/bluetooth/bluez/android/main.c):(service_register) service_id is 0x9. (HAL_SERVICE_ID_GATT)
E/BluetoothAdapterProperties: Property change not handled in Java land:5
E/BluetoothHeadsetClient: Could not bind to Bluetooth Headset Client Service with Intent { act=android.bluetooth.IBluetoothHeadsetClient }
E/BluetoothA2dpSink: Could not bind to Bluetooth A2DP Service with Intent { act=android.bluetooth.IBluetoothA2dpSink }
E/BluetoothAvrcpController: Could not bind to Bluetooth AVRCP Controller Service with Intent { act=android.bluetooth.IBluetoothAvrcpController }
```

---

***Log during the switch:***

```
#When switch to headphones
D/BluetoothHeadset: stopScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall()
D/HeadsetStateMachine: currentState = com.android.bluetooth.hfp.HeadsetStateMachine$Connected@ded9373
D/HeadsetStateMachine: Connected process message: 15, size: 1
D/HeadsetStateMachine: terminateScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall: Received
E/HeadsetStateMachine: terminateScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall:No present call to terminate
W/AudioPort: release: Port UNUSED 2
W/AudioPort: release: Port UNUSED 8
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: setParameters: key value pair android_mode=0;output_devices=32;output_flags=2;output_usecase=0
W/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: clearKeys: Unhandled argument: output_usecase=0
D/RouteManager: setVoiceVolume: gain=0
W/AudioPort: release: Port UNUSED 2
W/AudioPort: release: Port UNUSED 8
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: setParameters: key value pair android_mode=0;output_devices=8;output_flags=2;output_usecase=0
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: SelectedOutputDevices, current state: Headphones
W/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: clearKeys: Unhandled argument: output_usecase=0
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Yes" from domain "Route.HwCodec1IA.Playback.Applicable"
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Yes" from domain "Route.HwCodec1IA.Playback.NeedReconfigure"
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "No" from domain "Route.BtIA.Playback.Applicable"
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/EVENT_THREAD: void CEventThread::trig(void*, uint32_t): in
D/EVENT_THREAD: void CEventThread::trig(void*, uint32_t): out
D/RouteManager: doReconsiderRouting: Route state:
                                                -Previously Enabled Route in Input = <none>
                                                -Previously Enabled Route in Output = Media|BtIA
                                                -Selected Route in Input = <none>
                                                -Selected Route in Output = Media|HwCodec1IA
                                                -Route that need reconfiguration in Output = Media
D/RouteManager:         -executeMuteRoutingStage-
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: RoutageState, current state: Flow
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: ClosingPlaybackRoutes, current state: Media|BtIA
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: OpenedPlaybackRoutes, current state: <none>
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Mute" from domain "Routing.Sst.Mute.Bluetooth.Playback"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Mute" from domain "Routing.Sst.Mute.Media.Playback.Regular"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/RouteManager:         -executeDisableRoutingStage-
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: RoutageState, current state: Path
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: ClosingPlaybackRoutes, current state: BtIA
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: OpenedPlaybackRoutes, current state: Media
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Locked" from domain "Routing.Sst.Enable.VoiceProcessingLock.Uplink"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Locked" from domain "Routing.Sst.Enable.VoiceProcessingLock.Downlink"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/RouteManager:         -executeConfigureRoutingStage-
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: RoutageState, current state: Configure
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: ClosingPlaybackRoutes, current state: <none>
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: OpenedPlaybackRoutes, current state: Media|HwCodec1IA
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: SelectedOutputDevices, current state: Headphones
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Activated" from domain "Routing.Configure.HWCodec.Playback.DAC_LEFT"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Bind" from domain "Routing.Sst.Configure.Playback.Media.ToEarpieceOrHeadset"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Unbind" from domain "Routing.Sst.Configure.Playback.Media.Bluetooth"
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/MIXER/DAC/LEFT/DAC_L/SWITCH: Failed to open mixer control: Left Output Mixer From DAC_L
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/RouteManager:         -executeEnableRoutingStage-
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: RoutageState, current state: Path|Configure
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "UnLocked" from domain "Routing.Sst.Enable.VoiceProcessingLock.Uplink"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "UnLocked" from domain "Routing.Sst.Enable.VoiceProcessingLock.Downlink"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Enable" from domain "Routing.Enable.HWCodec.Playback.Headset"
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/OUTPUT/HEADPHONE/L_SWITCH: Failed to open mixer control: HP Left Analog Volume Switch
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/OUTPUT/HEADPHONE/R_SWITCH: Failed to open mixer control: HP Right Analog Volume Switch
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/MIXER/DAC/RIGHT/DAC_R/SWITCH: Failed to open mixer control: Right Output Mixer From DAC_R
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/RouteManager:         -executeUnmuteRoutingStage-
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: RoutageState, current state: Flow|Path|Configure
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Unmute" from domain "Routing.Mute.HWCodec.Playback.Headset"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Unmute" from domain "Routing.Sst.Mute.HwCodec.Playback.Internal"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Unmute" from domain "Routing.Sst.Mute.Media.Playback.Regular"
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/OUTPUT/HEADPHONE/ENABLED: ALSA: Control element count (2) and configurable scalar element count (1) mismatch
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/OUTPUT/HEADPHONE/UNMUTE/ENABLED: Failed to open mixer control: HP driver mute
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/OUTPUT/HEADPHONE/ANALOG/VOLUME: Failed to open mixer control: HP Analog Gain
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/RouteManager: doReconsiderRouting: DONE
D/EVENT_THREAD: void CEventThread::run() Do poll with timeout: -1
W/AudioPort: release: Port UNUSED 2
W/AudioPort: release: Port UNUSED 14
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: setParameters: key value pair android_mode=0;output_devices=8;output_flags=2;output_usecase=0
W/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: clearKeys: Unhandled argument: output_usecase=0
D/ThermalZone: ZoneName:STR0 movingAverageTemp:38925
D/RouteManager: setVoiceVolume: gain=0.533333
E/EM FG ALGO Iface:: Failed to get File Descriptor
D/ConnectivityService: updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 100] to 51
D/ConnectivityService: rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 100]
D/ConnectivityService: Network NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 100] was already satisfying request 1. No change.
D/ConnectivityService: notifyType AVAILABLE for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 100]
D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524290
I/ForegroundActivityPlugin: thread run
I/ForegroundActivityPlugin: pkg.equals(mLastForegroundActivity)
E/EM FG ALGO Iface:: Failed to get File Descriptor
I/ForegroundActivityPlugin: thread run
I/ForegroundActivityPlugin: pkg.equals(mLastForegroundActivity)
#When switch to bluetooth
W/AudioPort: release: Port UNUSED 2
W/AudioPort: release: Port UNUSED 14
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: setParameters: key value pair android_mode=0;output_devices=8;output_flags=2;output_usecase=0
W/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: clearKeys: Unhandled argument: output_usecase=0
D/RouteManager: setVoiceVolume: gain=1
W/AudioPort: release: Port UNUSED 2
W/AudioPort: release: Port UNUSED 14
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: setParameters: key value pair android_mode=0;output_devices=32;output_flags=2;output_usecase=0
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: SelectedOutputDevices, current state: ScoHeadset
W/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: clearKeys: Unhandled argument: output_usecase=0
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "No" from domain "Route.HwCodec1IA.Playback.Applicable"
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "No" from domain "Route.HwCodec1IA.Playback.NeedReconfigure"
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Yes" from domain "Route.BtIA.Playback.Applicable"
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/AudioIntelHal/AudioPlatformState: route-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/EVENT_THREAD: void CEventThread::trig(void*, uint32_t): in
D/EVENT_THREAD: void CEventThread::trig(void*, uint32_t): out
D/RouteManager: doReconsiderRouting: Route state:
                                                -Previously Enabled Route in Input = <none>
                                                -Previously Enabled Route in Output = Media|HwCodec1IA
                                                -Selected Route in Input = <none>
                                                -Selected Route in Output = Media|BtIA
                                                -Route that need reconfiguration in Output = Media
D/RouteManager:         -executeMuteRoutingStage-
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: RoutageState, current state: Flow
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: ClosingPlaybackRoutes, current state: Media|HwCodec1IA
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: OpenedPlaybackRoutes, current state: <none>
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Mute" from domain "Routing.Mute.HWCodec.Playback.Headset"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Mute" from domain "Routing.Sst.Mute.HwCodec.Playback.Internal"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Mute" from domain "Routing.Sst.Mute.Media.Playback.Regular"
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/OUTPUT/HEADPHONE/ENABLED: ALSA: Control element count (2) and configurable scalar element count (1) mismatch
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/OUTPUT/HEADPHONE/UNMUTE/ENABLED: Failed to open mixer control: HP driver mute
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/OUTPUT/HEADPHONE/ANALOG/VOLUME: Failed to open mixer control: HP Analog Gain
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/RouteManager:         -executeDisableRoutingStage-
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: RoutageState, current state: Path
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: ClosingPlaybackRoutes, current state: HwCodec1IA
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: OpenedPlaybackRoutes, current state: Media
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Locked" from domain "Routing.Sst.Enable.VoiceProcessingLock.Uplink"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Locked" from domain "Routing.Sst.Enable.VoiceProcessingLock.Downlink"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Disable" from domain "Routing.Enable.HWCodec.Playback.Headset"
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/OUTPUT/HEADPHONE/L_SWITCH: Failed to open mixer control: HP Left Analog Volume Switch
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/OUTPUT/HEADPHONE/R_SWITCH: Failed to open mixer control: HP Right Analog Volume Switch
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/MIXER/DAC/RIGHT/DAC_R/SWITCH: Failed to open mixer control: Right Output Mixer From DAC_R
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/RouteManager:         -executeConfigureRoutingStage-
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: RoutageState, current state: Configure
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: ClosingPlaybackRoutes, current state: <none>
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: OpenedPlaybackRoutes, current state: Media|BtIA
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: SelectedOutputDevices, current state: ScoHeadset
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Deactivated" from domain "Routing.Configure.HWCodec.Playback.DAC_LEFT"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Unbind" from domain "Routing.Sst.Configure.Playback.Media.ToEarpieceOrHeadset"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Bind" from domain "Routing.Sst.Configure.Playback.Media.Bluetooth"
W/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Unable to forward synchronize configurable element /Audio/TI/MIXER/DAC/LEFT/DAC_L/SWITCH: Failed to open mixer control: Left Output Mixer From DAC_L
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/RouteManager:         -executeEnableRoutingStage-
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: RoutageState, current state: Path|Configure
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "UnLocked" from domain "Routing.Sst.Enable.VoiceProcessingLock.Uplink"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "UnLocked" from domain "Routing.Sst.Enable.VoiceProcessingLock.Downlink"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/RouteManager:         -executeUnmuteRoutingStage-
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Selection criterion changed event: Criterion name: RoutageState, current state: Flow|Path|Configure
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: Configuration application request {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     Applying configurations {
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Unmute" from domain "Routing.Sst.Mute.Bluetooth.Playback"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:         Applying configuration "Unmute" from domain "Routing.Sst.Mute.Media.Playback.Regular"
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager:     } Applying configurations
D/RouteManager: audio-parameter-manager: } Configuration application request
D/RouteManager: doReconsiderRouting: DONE
D/EVENT_THREAD: void CEventThread::run() Do poll with timeout: -1
```

**How can I solve this problem? Can I solve this playing with the code of the app or it’s more a system problem?**

Comment: Feel free to message me directly. If you do in fact have a BT-350 and not a BT-300 there's a good chance you've been working with a pre-release model and we may need to set you up with a replacement. Our pre-release models often have little issues like this.

Comment: @MichaelMolina could you please email me at my username on Gmail? Some of the resources for BT-350 development seem limited and I have some questions about this, yet finding solid contacts is iffy at best...